# fetch all dates between two dates based on interval- sql

Tags: mysql, date

I have start date and end date, i want to fetch all dates between these two dates based on interval. `eg: start date:01-04-2018 and end date :20-04-2018 and interval is 3` i want output like 01-04-2018, 04-04-2018, 07-04-2018... etc
using sql and store the output in table.

Comment: Do you have all these dates in any table ?

Comment: i have only start_date, end_date and interval

Comment: Is your interval and date are always same ?

Comment: no that will differ, that i am assigning to variable.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not allowed you to get such result only by query,

You can create one procedure and insert into 1 table which you can use for your dates.

Try something like

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `calendar` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `calendar`(
IN startDate DATE , 
IN endDate DATE , 
IN inter INT(1))

BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `calendar` (`date` DATE);
     DELETE FROM `calendar`;

     WHILE startDate <= endDate DO
    INSERT INTO calendar VALUES(startDate);
    SET startDate := DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL inter DAY);
     END WHILE ;

 END$$

DELIMITER ;


CALL calendar('2018-04-01','2018-04-30',1);

SELECT * FROM calendar;
```

Now the **calendar table** has all the dates based on your **startDate, endDate and interval**.

You can try [Demo](http://rextester.com/WZT32812)